# Getting a POST variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, http-post

I am using C# with ASP.NET.

How do I check if a parameter has been received as a POST variable?

I need to do different actions if the parameter has been sent via POST or via GET.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Use this for GET values:

```
Request.QueryString["key"]
```

And this for POST values

```
Request.Form["key"]
```

Also, this will work if you don't care whether it comes from GET or POST, or the [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) collection:

```
Request["key"]
```

Another thing to note (if you need it) is you can check the type of request by using:

```
Request.RequestType
```

Which will be the verb used to access the page (usually GET or POST). `Request.IsPostBack` will usually work to check this, but only if the POST request includes the hidden fields added to the page by the ASP.NET framework.

Comment: I would not use Request["key"]...as this is the Items collection and gets a list of all objects stored in the page context.  This would also include cookie values.

Answer (score 7):

Use the

> Request.Form[]

for POST variables,

> Request.QueryString[]

for GET.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to using `Request.Form` and `Request.QueryString` and depending on your specific scenario, it may also be useful to check the `Page`'s `IsPostBack` property.

```
if (Page.IsPostBack)
{
  // HTTP Post
}
else
{
  // HTTP Get
}
```

Comment: not correct, IsPostBack is true if the form is either sent using GET or POST. The naming doesn't reflect the functionality