# Get textarea in codebehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, textarea

I am trying to get a textarea value from code behind using the following code.

```
  HtmlTextArea bodytextarea = new HtmlTextArea();
    bodytextarea = (HtmlTextArea)(this.FindControl("codearea"));
    string txtbod = bodytextarea.Value;
```

When i debug it i get a null reference exception saying that bodytextarea is null. I have to mention that my textarea is not runat="server" and i do not want to make it on server side. Any help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should add `runat="server"` to your `<TextArea id="myTextArea" runat="server" />`

like this you can directly get the value in code behind just by using the ID of the textarea

---

And if you dont wanna use server side then you have to use Jquery to get the value and create a `[webmethod]` method in your code behind so Jquery can call that method passing the value

---

or simply `string data = request["codearea"];`

Comment: I have a TextArea with `runat="server"` in my Content Page but I want to access it from my Master Page. I have a few Labels in my Content Page which I am calling it like this in my Master Page: `lblUser = (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label)ContentMain.FindControl("lblUser");`. How do I do the same with the TextArea?

Answer (score 1):

If it's not a runat="server" control, then  you have to get the value from the http context.
The value from the textarea will be treated as a (most likely) POST or GET variable.

see also: [Get POST data in C#/ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/976613/get-post-data-in-c-asp-net)

and [Getting a POST variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162495/check-post-variable-in-asp-net)

official MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.aspx

Comment: I updated my answer with a reference. You should check the last answer there. (using HttpContext.Current.Request[] for example)