# How to read HTML5 textarea's text with vb.net code at the back

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, html

I am trying to read the HTML5 Textarea's (not ASP.NET textbox control) text and pass it to my aspx.vb code at the back of the web page. How can I do it?

If can't, can I use JavaScript or other language pass the value to my back end vb code?

```
<textarea name="content"id="textarea" cols="90" rows="20"runat="server">
</textarea>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Knowing more about the structure of your page and how it is communicating with the server will help to answer your question. Please read[How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

on .aspx page, html text area -

```
<textarea runat="server" name="exampleTextArea" id="exampleTextArea"></textarea>
```

on .vb code behind page, you can get the value by calling this -

```
Me.exampleTextArea.Value
```

FULL EXAMPLE TO CALL THIS VALUE -

```
Dim textAreaValue as String = Me.exampleTextArea.Value
```

Comment: Seems the question are related to html textarea element

Comment: This IS HTML textarea element.

Comment: damn! you are right, and so your answer are problably most adherent to question, really sorry

Comment: Added full example to get value

Answer (score 1):

Here I tried one way may be it will help you

```
enter code here
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
<title>Pass Javascript Variables to Server</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
     function Set()
     {
        var a = '<%= inpt.ClientID %>';
        document.getElementById(a).value=jsVar;
     }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="Set()">
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>  
    <input id="inpt" type="text" runat="server"  />  
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtJSValue" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="btnJSValue" Text="Javascript Variable"runat="server" onclick="btnJSValue_Click"/>
</div>
</form>

</body>




*double click on button and type*`enter code here`
 enter code here
protected void btnJSValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtJSValue.Text = inpt.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Someone else wrote something about this (in c# but You can convert using some online converter).
Here is link :
[Get textarea in codebehind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609330/get-textarea-in-codebehind)

Of course, You can use `TextBox` and set `TextMode="Multiline"`... but If You won't then link above.

Answer (score 0):

Html5 textarea its just a misunderstand, but,anyway, set attribut name to your textarea, then if your textarea are in a runat server form, in the code behind, in the page load event you can easily test if  request["textareaName"] exist and if exist you can read the value directly from Request