# PHP $_POST analog in ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting a POST Variable in ASP.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162495/getting-a-post-variable-in-asp-net)

I just want to print all posted variables with their values.

`Request.Form` gives me only names with no values and `Request.InputStream` gives me the "*Timeouts are not supported on this stream.*" error.

How can I get all posted values like `$_POST` does in `PHP`?

Comment: I believe `Request.Form["name"]` is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`Request.Form`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.form.aspx) is a `NameValueCollection`, you can access posted data like this:

```
string postedName = Request.Form["name"];
```

Comment: This is bad. I just want to see all the post data w/o tinkering what variables I actually post.

Comment: This is good, this is how you get values via post,your question is not clear :/ What do you mean by seeing, you want to see them in (VS) debugger?

Comment: No, I'm using NewtonJSON to output them like so `return Content(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Request.Form));` I can see them in debugger but I just want to print them out. I don't believe there is no way to do that.

Comment: It seems that this is serialization problem, take a look at this: [how to convert NameValueCollection to JSON string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7003740/how-to-convert-namevaluecollection-to-json-string)

Answer (score 1):

Just use `Request`, like so:

```
var tmp = Request["formfield"]; // gets the value of 'formfield' from the request
```

However, unlike in PHP, keep in mind that the `Request` variable will contain both GET and POST parameters.

Comment: This is bad. I just want to see all the post data w/o tinkering what variables I actually post.

Comment: @EricPetroelje this won't compile in C# (you've used single quotes for string), right?

Comment: @des - you are right, sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view all Form key-value pairs for debugging you can do something like this:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string key in Form.Keys)
    dict.Add(key, Form[key]);
```

Then set a breakpoint after the loop and inspect the dictionary.

Comment: Alternatively, you can dig into the non-public members to find the values, but it's generally more of a hassle than it's worth.

Comment: error: 'System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlForm' does not contain a definition for 'Keys' (in Form.Keys)