# Send data to a database from a form Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form and would like to send data to the database but on clicking the button the data is not been sent to the database. When I try to debug it doesn't even goes to the breakpoint; so i'm wondering if the input button wasn't done correctly. The question is updated with the view and model

```
public ActionResult RequestItem(Requisition requisition)
    {
        IssueDAO dbdata = new IssueDAO();
        dbdata.connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TWCL_OPERATIONSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        getRequisition.reqDate = DateTime.Now; //Sets the transaction date to current date
        //getIssue.status = -1;
        Item item = new Item();
        try
        {
            dbdata.createRequisition(getRequisition, item);//Creates the issue in the database
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            LogWrite logWriter = new LogWrite(ex.ToString());
            ViewBag.errorMessage = "Unable to complete the Issue. Please see Log file for more Information";
            return View("RequisitionItem", getRequisition);


        }
        return View("RequisitionItem", getRequisition);


    }

 <input type="button" value="Request" name="Request" id="RequestItem" margin="50px" class="btn btn-default" />
```

ISSUEDAO

```
 /// <summary>
    /// This creates the request on the database
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="requisition">Issue object containing data passed from calling method</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool createRequisition(Requisition requisition, Item requisitionitem)
    {
        int rec_upd = 0;
        bool status;
        using (SqlConnection TWCLOPConnect = new SqlConnection(connectionString.ToString()))
        {
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
            SqlCommand requestcommand = new SqlCommand();


            //Command to update the requisition table with the header information
            requestcommand.Connection = TWCLOPConnect;
            requestcommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            requestcommand.CommandText = "requisition_sp_createRequisition";
            //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@docnum", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = issue.docNumber;
            //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@doctype", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = issue.docType;
            requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@req_num", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = requisition.reqNumber;
            //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@stores_rep_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = issue.processedbyDetails.employeeNum;
            //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@dept_rep_id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = issue.employeeDetails.employeeNum;
            //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@inventory_acc_indx", SqlDbType.Int).Value = issue.inventory_acccount;
            requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@description", SqlDbType.Int).Value =requisitionitem.description;
            requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@Req_Date", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = requisition.reqDate;
            requestcommand.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.Float);
            //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@department", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = issue.department;
            //issuecommand.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = issue.status;

            //Command to update the issueitem table with details of the transaction 
            command.Connection = TWCLOPConnect;
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.CommandText = "createRequestedItem";
            command.Parameters.Add("@req_num", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = requisition.reqNumber;
            //command.Parameters.Add("@inventory_acc_indx", SqlDbType.Int).Value = requisition.inventory_account;
            //command.Parameters.Add("@line_num", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters.Add("@itemnum", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            command.Parameters.Add("@qty", SqlDbType.Float);
            command.Parameters.Add("@issue_price", SqlDbType.Float);
            command.Parameters.Add("@expense_acc", SqlDbType.Int);
            //command.Parameters.Add("@inventory_acc", SqlDbType.Int);
            command.Parameters.Add("@uofm", SqlDbType.VarChar);
            try
            {
                TWCLOPConnect.Open();
                requestcommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                foreach (var item in requisition.items)
                {
                    //command.Parameters["@line_num"].Value = item.lineNum;
                    command.Parameters["@itemnum"].Value = item.itemNumber;
                    command.Parameters["@issue_price"].Value = item.price;
                    command.Parameters["@qty"].Value = item.quantity;
                    command.Parameters["@expense_acc"].Value = item.expense_account.index;
                    //command.Parameters["@inventory_acc"].Value = item.inventory_account.index;
                    command.Parameters["@uofm"].Value = item.selecteduomtext.Trim();
                    rec_upd = command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                TWCLOPConnect.Close();
            }
            if (rec_upd > 0)
            {
                status = true;
            }
            else
            {
                status = false;
            }
        }
        return status;
    }



  @model com.twcl.it.isms.Models.Requisition

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RequisitionNumber";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">


    function onFinishClick() {
        var rowCount = $('#myTable >tbody >tr').length;
        //window.alert(rowCount);
        if (rowCount === 1) {
            alert("Please add an item");
        }


        else {
             window.alert("You're item was successfully requested")
            window.location.replace("../Home/Index")
        }
        }

</script>



<h2>Requisition Screen</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Request Item</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.reqDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reqDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "reqDate", @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reqDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>


   <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.count, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })
       <text> @Html.Encode(Model.items.Count()) </text>
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.reqNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })

        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.reqNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "reqnum", @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.reqNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.department, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })

        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.department, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.department, new SelectList(Model.departmentsList, "Text", "Value"), new { @id = "department", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.department, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.employeeDetails, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })
        @*@Html.Label("Requested by:", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-2" })*@
        @if (Model.department == null)
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.employeeDetails.employeeNum, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "empname", @class = "form-control" })
        }
        else
        {
            @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.employeeDetails.employeeNum, new SelectList(ViewBag.ReceivedByReps, "Value", "Text"), new { @id = "empname", @class = "form-control" })
        }

        @*@Html.EditorFor(model => model.employeeName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })*@
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.employeeDetails.employeeNum, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.employeeDetails.firstName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.employeeDetails.lastName)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.employeeDetails.Name)




    <fieldset class="form-group">
        <div class="form-horizontal">
            <h4>Enter Requested Item(s)</h4>

            <hr />

            <div class="Row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, null, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "itemNumber", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.itemNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.description, null, new { @id = "description", @class = "form-control" })
                    @*<font color="blue">Please use your keyboard arrow keys to select items</font>*@
                    @*  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.description, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", @id = "txtItem" })*@
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                   <font color="red">@ViewBag.errorMessage</font>
                </div>
            </div>

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.item.lineNum)




            <div class="Row  form-group">
                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.item.price, new { @readonly = "readonly", @id = "price", @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.expense_account, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.item.expense_account.index, new SelectList(Model.accountlist, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.expense_account, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

                </div>


                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item.selecteduomtext, new { @id = "selecteduomtext" })
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.item.lineNum)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.items)


                <div class="col-md-5">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.quantity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.item.quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.quantity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>

                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.inventory_account, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })  

                    <div class="col-md-5">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.item.UofM, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "col-md-3" })
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.item.UofM, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Text", "Value"), new { @id = "uofm", @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.item.UofM, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>



                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-12">

                        <input type="submit" value="Add" name="Add" class="btn btn-default" width="89" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

                        <input type="button" value="Cancel" name="Cancel" margin="50px" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Cancel", "Requisition")' " class="btn btn-default" />


                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="form-group">
                    <table id="myTable">
                        <tr>
                            <th class="col-md-2">Item Number</th>
                            <th class="col-md-2">Item Description</th>
                            <th class="col-md-3">Expense Account</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">Quantity</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">UOM</th>
                            <th class="col-sm-1">Item Price</th>


                            <th></th>
                        </tr>
                        @{

                                if (@Model.items.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    foreach (var item in @Model.items)
                                    {
                                        <tr>
                                            <td class="col-md-3">@item.itemNumber</td>
                                            <td class="col-md-2">@item.description</td>
                                            <td class="col-md-3">@item.expense_account.getDescription</td>
                                            <td class="col-sm-1">@item.quantity.ToString()</td>
                                            <td class="col-sm-1">@item.selecteduomtext</td>
                                            <td class="col-sm-1">@item.price.ToString()</td>



                                            <td>
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.lineNum }) |
                                                @Html.ActionLink("Remove", "Remove", new { id = item.lineNum }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you would like to remove this item?'); " })
                                            </td>

                                        </tr>


                                }

                            }
                        }


                    </table>


                </div>



                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-4 col-md-12">


                        &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                        @*<input type="button" value="Finish" name="Issue" margin="50px" onclick="location.href='/Requisition/ViewRequisition' " class="btn btn-default" />*@
                        <input type="button" value="Request" name="Request" id="RequestItem" margin="50px" class="btn btn-default" />

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



    </fieldset>
</div>

                        }




@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Is this just plain HTML/ASP.NET, or are you using WebForms or something else?

Comment: .cshtml i'm using

Comment: I don't see anything indicating that your `RequestItem` function ever gets called. It is not enough to set `id="RequestItem"` - you should have something in your code that checks for that value on PostBack, and then calls the function.

Comment: can you give me an example

Comment: Take a look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162495/getting-a-post-variable

Comment: Since you are using a button, your form should be using POST, so the second example in the answer is what you want. So, something like `if (Request.Form["Request"] != null) {  RequestItem(requisition); }`

Comment: Post the IssueDAO class and post the view code.

Comment: I have edited the question @Waragi