# How can I use AngularJS to submit a form to my backend in c#?

Tags: javascript, c#, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I'm using REST ASP.NET and I need to get some values from my frontend form to research my database in my backend which is written in c#. I've tried using this article [Getting a POST variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2162495/getting-a-post-variable), but it did not work at all.

Comment: Hello Arthur, welcome to the SO community ! Please read this article https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Here you could post what you tried

Answer (score 0):

FYI, to submit some data to backend and get something result back - you should use your client angularjs service which is injects `$http`, `httpType` via constructor, e.g. below the simple function which is using GET method:

```
function someDataService($http, httpType) {
return {
         getUserSettings: getUserSettings
}

function getUserSettings(apiUrl, userId){
var httpSettings = {
        method: httpType.GET,
        url: apiUrl + '/getUserSettings?userId=' + userId,//e.g.  'http://localhost:5000/myAPI/getUserSettings?userId=1'
        headers: {}
      };
return $http(httpSettings)
    .then(function (res){return res;});
}
```